# IE 6/7 float height issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have 6 li elements that are floated to appear to be in a 2x3 grid:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Looks fine in everything except IE 6/7, there it looks like:

```
1 2 3
4   5
  6
```

The CSS I have is:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 278px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Items 1 and 4 have these styles on them:

```
li.row_start {
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

The problem (I'm guessing) is that the content in the li containers can have a variable height depending on the content inside. So in the example, item 2 would have a larger height than 1 and 3 so when item 5 is trying to float left, it is hitting the height/padding of item 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right on. The only real way to ensure that you get a layout like you want is to set the height on your items as well.